# Firebase phone auth doesn't work on lineageos

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, capacitor

I'm working on a capacitor app that uses capacitor-firebase-auth for phone auth using firebase. The app now has thousands of users and for the vast majority everything works fine. However, a few users per day are not able to login with phone number, and most of them are using a custom ROM like lineageos.

In order to debug the problem, I installed lineageos on one of my devices. Logcat of login with phone number looks like this:

```
05-26 13:23:51.630    97    97 W kswapd0 : type=1400 audit(0.0:109): avc: denied { write } for uid=0 path=2F6465762F6173686D656D2F7368617265645F6D656D6F72792F3836463635373034443144323445354233464446373530344133423843433132202864656C6574656429 dev="tmpfs" ino=242810 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:untrusted_app_tmpfs:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
05-26 13:23:51.649 14520 14560 I ContactDirectoryManager: deleted 0 stale rows which don't have any relevant directory
05-26 13:23:51.673 14520 14560 I ContactDirectoryManager: Discovered 0 contact directories in 406ms
05-26 13:23:52.163  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268017, service: Sentry, action: setExtraContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:52.167  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268018, service: Sentry, action: setTagsContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:52.171  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268019, service: Sentry, action: setUserContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:52.174  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268020, service: Sentry, action: addBreadcrumb, actionArgs: [{"timestamp":1.622028232145E9,"category":"ui.click","message":"text-button.singleTB > button.ion-activatable[type=\"button\"]"}]
05-26 13:23:52.347  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
05-26 13:23:52.370  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x11
05-26 13:23:52.375  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x12
05-26 13:23:52.385  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x13
05-26 13:23:52.395  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=12 sndbuf=163840 outq=0 send_len=48
05-26 13:23:52.395  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=17
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 17
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=18
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 18
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=19
05-26 13:23:52.396  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 19
05-26 13:23:55.227  5559  5559 W Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:110): avc: denied { read } for uid=10021 name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=7476 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-26 13:23:55.402  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
05-26 13:23:55.424  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x11
05-26 13:23:55.429  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x12
05-26 13:23:55.439  1228  2408 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x13
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=12 sndbuf=163840 outq=0 send_len=48
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=17
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 17
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:55.452  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=18
05-26 13:23:55.453  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 18
05-26 13:23:55.453  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Drv Event 103 (NL80211_CMD_VENDOR) received for wlan0
05-26 13:23:55.453  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Vendor event: wiphy=0 vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=19
05-26 13:23:55.453  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Ignore unsupported QCA vendor event 19
05-26 13:23:56.833  5559  5559 W Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:111): avc: denied { search } for uid=10021 name="340" dev="proc" ino=242919 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-26 13:23:57.216  6307  6307 E zzbf    : SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
05-26 13:23:57.251  1228  2266 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.firebase.auth.internal.ACTION_SHOW_RECAPTCHA pkg=eu.appiphany.blindmate cmp=eu.appiphany.blindmate/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity (has extras)} from uid 10118 on display 0
05-26 13:23:57.305  6307  6307 D Capacitor: App paused
05-26 13:23:57.362  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268021, service: Sentry, action: setExtraContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:57.364  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268022, service: Sentry, action: setTagsContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:57.366  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268023, service: Sentry, action: setUserContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:57.370  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268024, service: Sentry, action: addBreadcrumb, actionArgs: [{"timestamp":1.622028237358E9,"category":"console","data":{"extra":{"arguments":["platform paused"]},"logger":"console"},"level":"log","message":"platform paused"}]
05-26 13:23:57.421  6307 14612 W System  : Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
05-26 13:23:57.453  6307  6307 I Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.53bc4455e52f26fa9d19.js - Line 1 - Msg: platform paused
05-26 13:23:57.483    97    97 W kswapd0 : type=1400 audit(0.0:112): avc: denied { write } for uid=0 path=2F6465762F6173686D656D2F7368617265645F6D656D6F72792F3836463635373034443144323445354233464446373530344133423843433132202864656C6574656429 dev="tmpfs" ino=242810 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:untrusted_app_tmpfs:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
05-26 13:23:57.497  2681  2681 I GoogleInputMethodServic: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3362 
05-26 13:23:57.512  2681  2681 I GoogleInputMethodServic: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1943 
05-26 13:23:57.530  1228  1257 I ActivityManager: Displayed eu.appiphany.blindmate/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity: +220ms
05-26 13:23:57.553  6307  6307 D Capacitor: Saving instance state!
05-26 13:23:57.605  1228  4521 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.providers.calendar (pid 13526) has died
05-26 13:23:57.605  1228  4521 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 13526
05-26 13:23:57.668  1228  3487 I ActivityManager: Process com.android.calendar (pid 13511) has died
05-26 13:23:57.669  1228  3487 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 13511
05-26 13:23:57.818  6307 14612 E FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
05-26 13:23:57.913  6307  6307 E zzf     : Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
05-26 13:23:57.933  6307  6307 D Capacitor/App: Firing change: true
05-26 13:23:57.933  6307  6307 V Capacitor/App: Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
05-26 13:23:57.934  6307  6307 D Capacitor/App: No listeners found for event appStateChange
05-26 13:23:57.948  6307  6307 D Capacitor: App resumed
05-26 13:23:57.951  2681  2681 I GoogleInputMethodServic: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3362 
05-26 13:23:57.953  2681  2681 I GoogleInputMethodServic: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1943 
05-26 13:23:57.967  6307  6344 I FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
05-26 13:23:57.993  6307  6307 V Capacitor/Network: Notifying listeners for event networkStatusChange
05-26 13:23:57.994  6307  6307 D Capacitor/Network: No listeners found for event networkStatusChange
05-26 13:23:58.018  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 125401677, pluginId: PushNotifications, methodName: removeAllDeliveredNotifications
05-26 13:23:58.019  6307  6307 I Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.53bc4455e52f26fa9d19.js - Line 1 - Msg: platform resumed
05-26 13:23:58.019  6307  6529 V Capacitor: callback: 125401677, pluginId: PushNotifications, methodName: removeAllDeliveredNotifications, methodData: {}
05-26 13:23:58.039  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268025, service: Sentry, action: setExtraContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:58.047  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268026, service: Sentry, action: setTagsContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:58.053  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268027, service: Sentry, action: setUserContext, actionArgs: [{}]
05-26 13:23:58.057  6307  6529 V Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: Sentry1113268028, service: Sentry, action: addBreadcrumb, actionArgs: [{"timestamp":1.622028238004E9,"category":"console","data":{"extra":{"arguments":["platform resumed"]},"logger":"console"},"level":"log","message":"platform resumed"}]
05-26 13:23:58.147  1228  3487 I ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 11076) has died
05-26 13:23:58.148  1228  3487 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 11076
05-26 13:23:58.157  2681  2681 I AppBase : AppBase.onTrimMemory():784 onTrimMemory(): 5
05-26 13:23:58.179  2681  2681 I GoogleInputMethodServic: GoogleInputMethodService.onTrimMemory():4530 onTrimMemory(): 5
05-26 13:23:58.210  1228  2265 I ActivityManager: Process com.cyanogenmod.lockclock (pid 13607) has died
05-26 13:23:58.210  1228  2265 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 13607
05-26 13:23:58.280  6307  6344 E FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
05-26 13:23:58.301  3362  3362 D BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.service.SmsRetrieverApiService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
05-26 13:23:58.302  3362  3362 D BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.service.SmsRetrieverApiService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
05-26 13:23:58.308  6307  6307 W PhoneProviderHandler: PhoneAuth:onVerificationFailed:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin: PhoneAuth Sign In failure.
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:26)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzux.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:1)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuy.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:3)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-26 13:23:58.335  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Plugin:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-26 13:23:58.336  6307  6307 D Capacitor: Sending plugin error: {"save":false,"callbackId":"125401676","pluginId":"CapacitorFirebaseAuth","methodName":"signIn","success":false,"error":{"message":"PhoneAuth Sign In failure."}}
05-26 13:23:58.401  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.53bc4455e52f26fa9d19.js - Line 1 - Msg: Error at cfaSignIn Error: PhoneAuth Sign In failure.
05-26 13:23:58.401  6307  6307 I Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.53bc4455e52f26fa9d19.js - Line 1 - Msg: signIn false
05-26 13:23:58.417  6307  6307 E Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.53bc4455e52f26fa9d19.js - Line 1 - Msg: failed to login with phone unable to send code
05-26 13:23:58.459  2597  2597 D wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
```

with the relevant lines probably being

```
05-26 13:23:57.216  6307  6307 E zzbf    : SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
05-26 13:23:57.818  6307 14612 E FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
05-26 13:23:57.913  6307  6307 E zzf     : Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
05-26 13:23:58.308  6307  6307 W PhoneProviderHandler: PhoneAuth:onVerificationFailed:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

I now followed every suggestion that I could find in order to solve this problem:

- Copied SHA1 and SHA256 from Play App Signing to firebase console
- Ran signingReport from Android Studio and copied debug SHA1 and SHA256 to firebase console as well
- Enabled android device verification API
- Added `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'` to my app/build.gradle dependencies section

As I said, phone auth works fine for the vast majority of users, so there seems to be some problem connected to custom ROMs / lineageos. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found the solution: for some reason, google-services.json did not include my play store signing SHA1 key, despite it being present in firebase admin console. Solution: I removed the SHA1 key and added it again... Afterwards, google-services.json included my release SHA1 and phone auth works even on lineageos.

Apparently SHA256 is required for phone verification using safetynet which works on standard androids, and SHA1 is only required for the recaptcha flow which is required on non-standard androids. This explains why it worked for the vast majority of users.